# Find a word phrase in string/message (Not just single word, but a sentence) & return a response from array

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**Hello!**

Sorry for a perhaps strange title, i lacked a better sentence to try and document what I'm searching for (Description below).

*I've found it hard to put exact words onto this, and have below tried to provide a little example - with the result i want.*

I'm currently working on a script that if a user writes a message, the bot will reply if a certain phrase is found in their sentence.

The phrase it should catch is listed in a seperate json file, with the response it should give - if phrase found.

## Current code example

```
const autoResponse = require("./config/autoResponses.json");

    //first we read the message
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase()
    console.log(`Message detected: ${msg}`)
    
    //This here check the json filter if the message included a catched single word (This should be exact phrase)
    var automsg = autoResponse.help.filter((it => {
        return it.catch.toLowerCase().includes(msg)
    }))
    
    //output the json information
    automsg = automsg[0]

    //return the json array's response to console
    console.log(`Found appropiate response: ${automsg.response}`)
    if (!automsg) return console.log("Word not found in text");
```

In the autoResponse json it looks as following

```
{
    "help": [
        {
            "catch" :"get points",
            "response": "You need points?"
        },
        {
            "catch" :"im stuck",
            "response": "Looks like you said you are stuck"
        }
    ]
}
```

## Output Example from console.logs in code

---

**This here should work always (because the catch "get points" is found exact message - it crashes if i write "how do i get points" - because the "get points" cant be found in anything):**

Message detected: get points?

Found appropiate response: You need points?

---

**This here should not work (I only want it to trigger on phrase found, not single words in a message)**

Message detected: get

Found appropiate response: You need points?

---

**This here should not work (I only want it to trigger on phrase found, not single words in a message)**

Message detected: points

Found appropiate response: You need points?

## Description

So in this case, if a user writes: how do i get points? - the accordingly response would return. (Because it found "get points" in the user message)

I've tried using return it.catch.toLowerCase().include(msg) & splitting it into arrays

But then the bot would reply: You need points? - if you wrote **get** -or- **points** -or- **get points**.
It wouldn't detect "get points" (return undefined) in a sentence like: How do i **get points**?

I don't want the bot to reply if words such as **get**, **points**, **im**, **stuck** was found in a sentence - i first want it to trigger when the exact combined phrase in **catch** (*get points, im stuck ... etc*) is found throughout a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for,
look for catch in msg so you it will only pass if msg includes the catch phrase.

```js
return msg.includes(it.catch.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Oh, that there works exactly as expected! - I guess i looked myself blind on having it.catch.includes(), instead of swapping them.. I did not think of this at all. Very simple and nice solution, thank you so much!